# Get memory usage of computer in Windows with Python

Tags: python, memory, winapi, memory-management, pywin32

How can I tell what the computer's overall memory usage is from Python, running on Windows XP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to use the [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) module.  Something like this:

```
import wmi
comp = wmi.WMI()

for i in comp.Win32_ComputerSystem():
   print i.TotalPhysicalMemory, "bytes of physical memory"

for os in comp.Win32_OperatingSystem():
   print os.FreePhysicalMemory, "bytes of available memory"
```

Comment: +1. It will be trivial to change this to fetch the correct data.

Comment: @NigelHeffernan The existing answer already uses Win32_OperatingSystem to access FreePhysicalMemory.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I should either drink more coffee or go home

Answer (score 23):

You can also just call GlobalMemoryStatusEx() (or any other kernel32 or user32 export) directly from python:

```
import ctypes

class MEMORYSTATUSEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwLength", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("dwMemoryLoad", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("ullTotalPhys", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("ullAvailPhys", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("ullTotalPageFile", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("ullAvailPageFile", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("ullTotalVirtual", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("ullAvailVirtual", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("sullAvailExtendedVirtual", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        # have to initialize this to the size of MEMORYSTATUSEX
        self.dwLength = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(MEMORYSTATUSEX, self).__init__()

stat = MEMORYSTATUSEX()
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ctypes.byref(stat))

print("MemoryLoad: %d%%" % (stat.dwMemoryLoad))
```

Not necessarily as useful as WMI in this case, but definitely a nice trick to have in your back pocket.

Comment: This one was awesome, had no idea you could do this in Windows.

Comment: That's a return in __init__? Why would you do that?

Comment: The super call can be omitted because dwLength has been initialized before and the other _fields_ does not need to be initialized.

Comment: if i import `ctype` in unix, the `dir(ctype)` wouldn't have the `ctype.windll`, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the performance counters in WMI. I've done something similar but with disk space instead.

A very useful link is the [Python WMI Tutorial by Tim Golden](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html).