# How to find the current System Cache Size on Windows?

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi, ctypes

Searched high and low but haven't been able to find an API call to retrieve the current size of the (File) System Cache on Windows.

[GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017659/450917) - retrieves the Total, Free, Used, and Swap stats.

[GetSystemFileCacheSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - returns the Minimum and Maximum it could be, not very helpful.

I also tried the Windows extensions, which returned the unhelpful numbers below.  Looks like it could be anywhere from 1mb to 2gb?

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetSystemFileCacheSize()
(1048576L, 2143289344L, 0L)
```

What is the correct API call to get this information?  I see it available in the task manager, so it must be in there somewhere?  Here's a screen shot and the numbers I'm looking for:

[image]

Would prefer a python solution, but C/C++ would help a lot.

Comment: You can try to get programmatically 4 performance counters `Cached` = `\Memory\Modified Page List Bytes` + `\Memory\Standby Cache Reserve Bytes` + `\Memory\Standby Cache Normal Priority Bytes` + `\Memory\Standby Cache Core Bytes`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I wasn't able to find an api call after many hours of searching.  Looking up these perf counters and why they didn't match the task manager led me to a mailing list where a post pointed to the call below. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I did finally figure it out:

```
import ctypes
psapi = ctypes.WinDLL('psapi')

class PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    ''' Struct for Windows .GetPerformanceInfo().
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683210
    '''

    _DWORD = ctypes.c_ulong
    _SIZE_T = ctypes.c_size_t

    _fields_ = [
        ('cb', _DWORD),
        ('CommitTotal', _SIZE_T),
        ('CommitLimit', _SIZE_T),
        ('CommitPeak', _SIZE_T),
        ('PhysicalTotal', _SIZE_T),
        ('PhysicalAvailable', _SIZE_T),
        ('SystemCache', _SIZE_T),
        ('KernelTotal', _SIZE_T),
        ('KernelPaged', _SIZE_T),
        ('KernelNonpaged', _SIZE_T),
        ('PageSize', _SIZE_T),
        ('HandleCount', _DWORD),
        ('ProcessCount', _DWORD),
        ('ThreadCount', _DWORD),
    ]

    def __init__(self, getinfo=True, *args, **kwds):
        super(PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION, self).__init__(
              ctypes.sizeof(self), *args, **kwds)
        if (getinfo and not
            psapi.GetPerformanceInfo(ctypes.byref(self), 
                                     self.cb)):
            raise WinError()

    @property
    def cache_info(self):
        return self.SystemCache * self.PageSize

def get_cache_info():
    return PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION().cache_info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_cache_info())
```