# Displaying current RAM along with its type and CPU's cache size using Python

Tags: python, cpu, ram, cpu-cache

I'm currently trying to code a Python program to display the amount of RAM, my system has along with its type and CPU's cache size. It would really helpful if anyone could help me figure this out.
Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows: For amount of RAM, [use `ctypes` to call `GetPerformanceInfo` on a `psapi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14396610/7194773) [WinDLL instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033733/call-to-getmodulehandle-on-kernel32-using-python-c-types/67155295#67155295) or `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` on a `kernel32` WinDLL instance. For cache, [use `GetLogicalProcessorInformation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150300/7194773) on a `kernel32` WinDLL instance. For DRAM type, [use SMBIOS or Win32_PhysicalMemory WMI class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14227777/7194773) and make a [WMI query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016030/7194773) (example using the `Win32_Process` class).